# Howto extend a form via ajax depending on select

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, forms

I have a form with a country select. The form should be extended with new input fields depending on the selected country.

Most of the tutorials i found on google are for ajax submits after filling a forum.

Can somebody recommend a tutorial/howto on howto extend a form via ajax on a select change?

Comment: google 'railscast dynamic form',  there are several railscasts that deal with this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use something like this. Of cousre `url`, `country_data`, and `custom_part` must be handled according your app. And the returned data comes from your app, better without layout, only the part what you want to add.

```
$.get("url", country_data, function(returned_data){ $(".custom_part").html(returned_data) })
```